# Add image as intro and outro to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Here is basically what I'm trying to do.

I have two files : 1. image.png 2. video.mp4

I'm trying to create a new video file (mp4) with :

IMAGE.PNG for the first 5 seconds

VIDEO.MP4 for the duration of the file VIDEO.MP4 (example 60 seconds)

IMAGE.PNG for 5 seconds

is it possible in FFMPEG?

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -loop 1 -t 5 -i image.png -i video.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0][2][1:v][1:a][0][2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

- The [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter generates silent audio as filler for proper concatenation. The concat filter will automatically pad the silent audio, so you only need a very short duration for anullsrc (this example uses `-t 0.1`).
- This assumes your image is the same width, height, and aspect ratio as `video.mp4`. If it is not then you'll have to filter the image to match with the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad), [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), or [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filters. There are plenty of example of how to do this on Stack Exchange.
- You didn't provide any info on your inputs or `ffmpeg` build so I only provided this basic example.
- An alternative method is to use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) which can avoid re-encoding `video.mp4`, but it can be somewhat harder to use because you'll have to make the video from the image first and made sure all of the parameters are the same as `video.mp4`. See the [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate), and again search Stack Exchange for dozens of examples.